# How would you properly use System.Data.SqlClient to populate data with a query that contains a DateTime?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

The purpose of this application is for the user to select a specific seat on a specific day for a football game. The purpose of this specific part of this application is to populate the drop-down menus of a combo box when the previous one has a SelectedIndexChange() event. I recently added the functionality of being able to choose 1 of 8 dates to check for a seat, which ended up filling my seat drop-down with ALL of the seats in that specific section/row, not including the date. I tried fixing that by updating my query, but it still doesn't work properly. Here's the code:

```
        private void ComboRows_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateBtnCheckPriceEnabledState();

            //ComboSeats.Items.Clear();

            if (ComboRows.SelectedItem is string selectedRow && ComboSections.SelectedItem is string selectedSection && ComboGameDates.SelectedItem is DateTime selectedDate)
            {
                string seatConnectionString = Constants.connectString;

                using SqlConnection seatConnection = new(seatConnectionString);

                string seatQuery = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SeatNumber) FROM Stadium WHERE SectionRow = @SectionRow AND Section = @Section AND GameDate = @GameDate";

                using SqlCommand seatCommand = new(seatQuery, seatConnection);

                try
                {
                    seatCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SectionRow", selectedRow);
                    seatCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Section", selectedSection);
                    seatCommand.Parameters.Add("@GameDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = selectedDate;

                    seatConnection.Open();

                    int seatCount = (int)seatCommand.ExecuteScalar();

                    for (int seatNumber = 1; seatNumber <= seatCount; seatNumber++)
                    {
                        string seatNumStr = seatNumber.ToString();
                        ComboSeats.Items.Add(seatNumStr);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

Now it won't populate the combo box drop-down at all. If anyone could shed some light and/or give me some guidance that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

I initially tried updating my query to be:

```
string seatQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Stadium WHERE SectionRow = @SectionRow AND Section = @Section AND GameDate = @GameDate";
```

as it worked previously when I was not trying to filter by GameDate as well. This also did not work.

Comment: you might have a problem related to DateTime type so they are not exactly equal. Can you provide a data sample too? You might want to change the query by extracting the date part cast(getdate() as date)

Comment: In SQL Server a `datetime` is a specific instant in time (down to 1/300th second resolution, anyway). As already mentioned, if the `GameDate` is a `date` column you'll want to only be comparing using the date portion of `@GameDate`. If it's a `datetime` column you'll need to coerce the range of time appropriately.

Comment: You can put a breakpoint in the for loop to see if the sql statement can return the value you want. If no corresponding value is returned, it can be considered that the database data type does not correspond to datetime